# How to redirect to the same page after a POST request

Tags: jsf-2

How to redirect to the same page (I don't know the page; the redirection is done inside a menu shared by several pages) ?

I tried

```
return "?faces-redirect=true";
```

at the end of the action method, but I received an error message because it is not possible to find a navigation case for "?faces-redirect=true".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to supply a valid view ID in the outcome and not only a query string. You can obtain the current view ID by [`UIViewRoot#getViewId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewId%28%29).

```
String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
return viewId + "?faces-redirect=true";
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply return `null` or an empty string from your application action.

As per JSF2.2 spec, section 7.4.1:

> If the outcome returned by the application action is **null or the empty
>   string**, and none of the navigation cases that map to the current view
>   identifier have a non-null condition expression, the same view must be
>   re-displayed.

Comment: You can also have a void method. It's even more clear. It's the same and works perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't perform a redirect. This performs a forward.